# Android, update sql db with data through api call every 24 hours and update google maps markers

Tags: java, android, sql, api, maps

I'm working on an app where I have to display petrol stations on a map. I'm fetching those by an API call to a server and receiving them as JSON data. I later filter out the ones I need and store them in my SQLite DB.

Here comes the tricky part, atleast for me: 
I want to update my map with markers when the application starts, using the data inside my database. I want to fetch the data using the api call to the server once every 24 hours and replace the current data in the db with the new one (reason being that there might be new petrol stations available). I want to do this replacement when the application starts IF 24 hours have passed in realtime since the last update.

Where do I start? It feels like bad practice using alarmmanagers for this particular case, cause I don't want to fire an intent every 24 hours or start the app, rather do the update when the application is started by the user and check whether or not 24 hours have passed.

Comment: Have you found a way?

Comment: Yes, I saved an variable in SharedPreferences for the last date the api call was done. When the app runs I check if it has been 24 hours or not (taking into account +1 and -1 hours changes), if that's the case the intentservice fetches the stations again and removes the old stations from the db and adds the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use job scheduler for this purpose.

Comment: My application targets 4.4+, job scheduler is only available for 5.0 and upwards(Lollipop). I don't really want to use a custom library like JobSchedulerCompat